# Which is truer between "can we appreciate" and "can't we appreciate"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, differences

To me these two words mean the same thing, but I'm confused which one is the truer of the two words, or do they mean different things? If the same, can you explain which word is more correct? "Can we appreciate her" or "Can't we appreciate her". Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "which is the truer?". _Can we appreciate her_ asks if it is possible to do so, _Can't we..._ suggests that we ought to be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter has more emphasis.

*"Can we appreciate....?"* is already implying that we ought to, but not very strong.

*"Can't we appreciate ...?"* heavily implies that we ought to appreciate it, showing discontent for not already doing so.

Both aren't true or false, because both are [rhetorical questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). They are assertions masquerading as questions. Thus, neither of them is "more true", but the latter has more emphasis.

Comment: I'sd say the first is a suggestion, the second an exhortation, not statements of fact.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't say they are facts, but assertions. Assertions are often unsupported. The rhetorical questions is somewhat of the search for validation.

Comment: [Collins'])https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/statement) default definition is 'A statement is something that you say or write which gives information in a formal or definite way.'  Also, a definition I recognise,  'Statement (proposition): the meaning intended by any sentence which can be said to be true or false.' [[Loyno](http://people.loyno.edu/~folse/typesofstatements.html). So questions, many exclamations, and all recommendations / exhortations / commands are different from statements

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But I didn't even use the word statement. Also, those rhetorical questions *do* state something about the askers beliefs. I'm not sure what we are discussing here, btw. It doesn't seem all too relevant for the Q&A.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "a positive statement, usually made without an attempt at furnishing evidence" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assertion

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/assertion): << **assertion** a positive statement or declaration, often without support or reason ... synonyms: claim, contention, allegation >> and << **declaration**: a positive, explicit, or formal statement; proclamation >> 'Can't we appreciate her(!)' means something like 'Come on ... let's lay aside baggage and show her some appreciation!' A statement is of the form 'She is lazy / a hero', stating something whose truth value can be assessed. Sentences like 'Let's do X' and 'Is this a Y?' are not making statements.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oxford offers for **assertion** "[countable] a statement saying that you strongly believe something to be true", which "We should X" *is*, and it is *precisely* the assertion behind the rhetorical question. You can *state* an opinion.

Comment: But 'Let's be nicer to her' is an exhortation, not a statement, even though there is a covert 'I think we ought to be nicer to her' statement that could be deduced. 'Aren't you going by train?' entails the statement 'I believe you could go by train' and the opinion 'Trains are available'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I literally said "They are assertions masquerading as questions.". There isn't a *literal* statement in there, that *is* the point of the rhetorical question.

Comment: "Can't we appreciate ...?" is a hortation masquerading as a question.